# Rake task with multiple parameters and model access not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am getting the following error running my rake task

```
rake store_reports["1", "2"]
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'store_reports[1,'
```

My rake task takes 2 parameters and needs to access models inside it. Here is the task

```
task :store_reports, [:start_date, :end_date] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts args.start_date
end
```

I referenced both of there stackoverflow questions, but the first answer did not work, and in the second one the author seems to have solved it but he never posted his answer.

[rake aborted! undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493337/rake-aborted-undefined-method-map-for-namesymbol)
[rake task with multiple parameters - I got stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713654/rake-task-with-multiple-parameters-i-got-stuck)

Heres some extra info. Where I run `rake -T` I dont see my rake task there

Comment: where do you store this task?

Comment: the task is in lib/task

Comment: I dont understand why my answer was deleted. The question was that rails couldnt build the task. If the file would be somewhere except lib/tasks and doesn't have a .rake ending, the message would be the same. So i think my answer made sense, maybe not for this case, but in general. Unfortunately I cant undelete or comment my answer, so i post it here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try

```
rake store_reports["1","2"]
```

as per [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task).

the parser is not liking the space between your parameters

Comment: I know this is an old post but any idea why the rake task wasnot appearing in the list? I am having the same error

Comment: @Brett - It's not that the parsing is stupid, it's just how shells work.  If you put in a space, then ruby sees it as to separate arguments.  You could put quotes around the whole thing to make it look like one argument, which would work fine :) Just realise that it's your shell doing something to your input before ruby gets it.

Comment: FYI, you _shouldn't_ need to put quotes around the individual arguments. In my stock macOS terminal I was able to run `rake store_reports[1,2]` just fine.